# Regular expression confusion on how to specify input

Tags: regex

How would I define a regular expression for strings from the alphabet set `{a,b}` where the strings only have exactly 2 `a`s?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
b*ab*ab*
```

---

It looks something like this:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is a look ahead:

```
^(?=([^a]*a){2}[^a]*$)[ab]*$
```